# Golang медленно выполняются тесты

Tags: golang, производительность

Создаю один простой тест, который при запуске `go test` выполняется очень долго. Секунд 10, хотя пишет по результатам 0.025s. Может, потому что каждый раз происходит билд?

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)


func TestGetModelById(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, 1, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Именно поэтому (и скорее всего это происходит в Windows, верно?).

Можно поробовать несколько улучшить ситуацию, согласно вот этой части
документации `go help test`:

> Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled
>   as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.

Проще говоря, Вы можете все свои тесты сделать отдельным пакетом (например, `all_test`) или пакетами (например, для внутреннего пакета `foo` сделать пакет `foo_test`) и сделать им `go install`.
Следующий запуск `go test ./...` "подберёт" эти пакеты из `$GOPATH/pkg` без компиляции.

С другой стороны, всё равно будет произведён синтез временного бинарника для тестирования и линковка этих пакетов к нему.
Поэтому если тестов мало, такой способ может не улучшить ситуацию.

Посему, возможно, единственный способ это ускорить сборку (положить `$GOPATH` на SSD, например) или, если возможно, использовать для основной разработки что-нибудь пошустрее (систему на базе GNU/Linux или *BSD или Mac OS), и на Windows проводить "финальное" тестирование перед сборкой для бинарного релиза.

Comment: go 1.6, ubuntu 14.04, SSD, использую glide как менеджер пакетов, а вот после go install все перестает работать (go test) и приходится удалять папку pkg